# Git says origin already exists, when it REALLY doesn't

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set up git, I am starting with everything fresh, and I've following all the steps in https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo (except instead of creating a readme file, I did git init in my source code project folder and did 'git add *.*')
but heres what happens when I try to add roigin:

```
E:\eclypse\workspace [master]> git remote add origin https://github.com/my-repo/android-projects.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
E:\eclypse\workspace [master +0 ~7 -0]> git remote -v
origin
upstream
E:\eclypse\workspace [master +0 ~7 -0]> git remote rm origin
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'
```

I know the remote DOES NOT already exist, here is my config file:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
```

Whats going on?
NOTE: I know I can just use another name besides 'origin' but there is something wrong here and I want to figure out what. And I did try using a different name for origin, I run into issues later down the line.

update, here are the contents of my .gitconfig file

```
[user]
name = Siavash Bonakdar
email = clumsygenius@gmail.com
```

Comment: Do you have a `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: there is a .git folder in my root, and under that there is a file called 'config'. I dont see 'getconfig'.

Comment: Yes, that's your repository's config file.  Do you have a global config file in your home directory?

Comment: Ok I found it, I will post contents above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information about known remotes are just stored as a normal git configuration.

git stores its configuration in (potentially) three different places. For system wide configuration, personal configuration and repository specific configuration.

You can list all the different configuration:

```
git config --list --system
git config --list --global
git config --list --local
```

One of those places should list something about `remote.origin.*`.

You can edit the corresponding file using one of these:

```
git config --edit --system
git config --edit --global
git config --edit --local
```

Answer (score 0):

A remote corresponds to two things:

- A piece of configuration in `.git/config`
- A set of refs, in the namespace `refs/remotes/$remote`

I believe you have the second, but not the first (most likely because you removed the remote from your `.git/config` file earlier).

`git remote rm` tries to remove both, but the fact that the refs should be stored in `refs/remotes/$remote` is stored in the configuration file, and this information does not exist anymore, hence git cannot remove these refs.

You can either re-create manually the `remote` section in the config file to allow `git remote rm` to run properly, or use `git update-ref -d` on each ref to delete (use `git for-each-ref` to find out which).